# Create zoomable Google Chart out of milliseconds

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have to create a chart by our website visitor numbers (preferably similar to those of Analytics by Google).

I got a text file filled with the time of visits in milliseconds like this:

> [1505385301633, 0]
> [1505219341916, 0]
> [1504999958757,
>   0]
> [1504854145481, 0]
> [1504601608015, 0]
> [1504385667271,
>   0]
> [1504380372409, 0]
> [1504112805811, 0]
> [1503866251230,
>   0]
> [1503865512105, 0]
> ...

This is what I got so far working with Google Charts:
https://jsfiddle.net/2djpec3s/

Controls: drag to zoom, right-click to reset

```
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], 'language':'de'});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // not in use yet
      /* var date = new Date(1507130849370);
      date = msToDate(date);

      function msToDate(date) // milliseconds to year, month, day
            {
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var date = date.getDate(); // day

            return new Date(year, month, date);
            } */

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Date', 'Visitors'],
          [new Date(1507130849370), 1],
          [new Date(1507149651188), 1],
          [new Date(1507191655367), 1],
          [new Date(1507212560124), 1],
          [new Date(1507231742263), 1],
          [new Date(1507305748865), 1],
          [new Date(1507455848163), 1],
          [new Date(1507612393800), 1],
          [new Date(1507825666582), 1],
          [new Date(1507881840738), 1],
          [new Date(1507921803759), 1],
          [new Date(1508001467740), 1]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Statistics',
          explorer: {
            actions: [
                'dragToZoom',
              'rightClickToReset'
            ],
            maxZoomIn: 0.001
          },
          hAxis: {
            gridlines: {
                            units: {
                years: {format: ['y']},
                                months: {format: ['MMMM']},
                            days: {format: ['E, d. MMM']},
                            hours: {format: ["HH:mm 'Uhr'"]},
                minutes: {format: ["HH:mm 'Uhr'"]}
                            }
            },
            minorGridlines: {
                units: {
                days: {format: ['d. MMM']},
                hours: {format: ["H 'Uhr'"]},
                minutes: {format: ['HH:mm']}
                }
            }
          },
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
```

The problem is I just can't figure out, if or how the data can be joined/stacked in an specific zoom level.

An alternative way I'd like to avoid is to create up to 4 charts for year, month, day and hour and let them visually be swappable by using a selection box.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to have your zoom level be how many datapoints you want to show per pixel. The following examples uses the average in the sample range but you could take peak value or whatever works for your application.
This scales well to huge arrays as the number of data points you have is always equal to width and maximum complexity is width * resolution. If you always want to take all the datapoints just set resolution to a high number (or leave it out)

```
function getSampledData(data, zoomLevel, scrollPosition, width, resolution) {
    const sampledData = [];
    const skip = Math.max(1, zoomLevel / resolution);

    // iterate over each pixel of chart width
    for(let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
       let total = 0;
       // scrollPosition is the start pixel position of virtual scroll
       let startPoint = (i * zoomLevel) + (scrollPosition * zoomLevel);
       // zoom level is how many data points you want to show per pixel
       for(let j = startPoint; j < startPoint + zoomLevel && j < data.length; j += skip) {
          total += data[j];
       }

       sampledData.push(total / resolution);
    }
    return sampledData;
}
```